# How to change a table cell from $ to € in Pages?

Tags: macos, pages

I'm using Pages' Invoice templates, and it's been grand so far. Now I need to send an invoice to Europe, and the sums need to be in euros rather than dollars. How can I change the currency type in the table?

Comment: And as soon as I ask, I think to check the obvious place. Right. In the Inspector, under Table/Format. Right, then.

Comment: I recommend making that an answer, and accepting it when it allows you to. It might benefit others in the future.

Comment: Yes please - make an answer - we encourage "jeopardy" questions as long as the answer goes in the answer section and not in the comments or the question.

Comment: Yup. As a new user it wouldn't let me answer my own question until it had timed out.

Comment: Grrr - I've got plenty of rep - so why don't you answer it yourself and send a comment on mine once you can accept your answer. I wanted people to see the answer in the mean time, but would rather you get credit for this once the timeouts pass.

Comment: No worries. Your answer includes a handy picture. Keep the rep. I'd have upvoted your answer, too. But again, new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inspector to change the table cell formatting symbol.

[image: Pages Cell Format inspector view]